# How to access the GUI of UEFI on ASUS Laptops?

Tags: uefi, asus-laptop

My Asus laptop has UEFI firmware and GPT partitions on the disk. It is running Windows 7 x64.

I've heard a lot about these GUIs. How do I access them? As using the F2 button simply brings up the plain old BIOS UI.

Comment: UEFI doesn't necessarily equate to GUI.  My ThinkPad has UEFI but still uses a text-based UI for system configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if pressing the button at boot that corresponds to the boot settings doesn't show a UEFI bios, then I'm afraid you don't have it. Unless you just recently bought this laptop, I highly doubt that it came with UEFI and assume that you are mixing your laptop with another ASUS model. There is no way to upgrade to UEFI either, as it utilizes too much storage space for a normal BIOS storage to hold.

Comment: Yes, I just bought this laptop and it has UEFI and GPT partition scheme disks. How and which firmware do I flash for the GUI UEFI for my ASUS laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the confusion here is that you expect a graphical interface just because you have UEFI rather than BIOS firmware.  These are unrelated.

Basically you can have:

1. Firmware loaded with a BIOS program. Classic interface.
2. Firmware loaded with a BIOS program. GUI interface.
3. Firmware loaded with a UEFI program. Classic interface.
4. Firmware loaded with a UEFI program. GUI interface.

Some of the first EFI firmwares were showcases and also used a graphical interface. But this is not because it was [U]EFI, but because they were show cases.